# Start: Applet is not initialized in Java application

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

Friends I am writing a simple Swing Application. But when i am run this, "Start: Applet is not initialized" window is shown. My main class is

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new GameFrame());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(false);
}

}
```

My sub class is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class GameFrame extends JPanel {
GameFrame(){
    setFocusable(true);

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawString("Hello am Haris..!!", 100, 100);
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon();
    Image i = ic.getImage();
    g2d.drawImage(i, 500, 200, null);

}

}
```

Comment: `Start: Applet is not initialized` Stop: code is for an application, not an applet.

Comment: That's not an applet, it's a desktop application

Answer (score 1):

An applet should subclass the `java.applet.Applet` class. It need not have a `main()` method, as it will not get called by default. Subclasses of `Applet` typically override the `init()`, `start()`, `stop()` and `destroy()` methods.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html.